# Can I subtract two fields from firebase?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, axios

I'm working o a weight tracking app using vue and getting data from firebase using axios.

My database looks something like this:
[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to subtract the two most recent weights and display that value?

Heres the backend:

```
app.get("/weight", (req, res) => {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  let item = [];

  db.collectionGroup("Weight")
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        item.push(doc.data());
      });
      res.send(item);
    });
});
```

And how Im reciving it on the frontend:

```
mounted() {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3000/Weight`)
      .then((res) => {
        this.weights= res.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
db.collectionGroup("Weight")
  .orderBy("date", "desc")
  .limit(2)
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    const weight1 = snapshot.docs[0].data().Weight;
    const weight2 = snapshot.docs[1].data().Weight;
    res.send(weight1-weight2);
  });
```